# Python - Get matched string percentage along with the string

Tags: python, string, substring, matching, metrics

I want to match a string to certain keywords and get the percentage and the substring that was matched to my keyword. E.g.
I have a list of keywords

```
keywords = ['Projekt-Nr.:', 'Projektbezeichnung:', 'Anlagenklassifizierung:', 'Arbeiten / Gewerk:']
```

and some unknown text e.g.

```
s = "Projekthezeichnung: —_[H- Kloster Eig i Krankenhaus"
```

I want my keywords to be searched in this string so that it returns me the partially matched string.

'Projektbezeichnung:' should match 'Projekthezeichnung:' with over 95% accuracy (I am already using cdifflib for that) but cdifflib doesn't return the substring my keyword was matched with.

**How can I get the unknown substring that my keyword was partially matched with?**

Any help would be quite useful, thanks!

Comment: So if something is close to `—_[H-`, should it also count? i.e. "substring"s in the unknown text are those seperated by space?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://pypi.org/project/editdistance/0.3.1/

Comment: @MustafaAydın yes they are separated by spaces

Comment: @MazziottiRaffaele yes but i need the word my keyword was matched with as it is unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`difflib`'s [`get_close_matches`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) seems suitable:

```
from difflib import get_close_matches as gcm

keywords = ['Projekt-Nr.:', 'Projektbezeichnung:', 'Anlagenklassifizierung:', 'Arbeiten / Gewerk:']
unk_text = "Projekthezeichnung: —_[H- Kloster Eig i Krankenhaus"
words = unk_text.split()

result = [gcm(kw, words, n=len(words), cutoff=0.8) for kw in keywords]
# [[], ['Projekthezeichnung:'], [], []]
```

Each sublist of the `result` list contains "close" matches to the corresponding keyword.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you!